# Spring & Hibernate: no session bound to the thread

Tags: hibernate, spring, session, transactions

Trying to get Spring's transaction management to work but it's not going as I hoped.

I get an exception when requesting anything that requires my database:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Opening Hibernate Session
DEBUG: org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 12897642913
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
DEBUG: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
14-nov-2010 20:51:31 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

I already moved my properties to my Spring context to see if that went any better but no.
My Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/kidscalcula" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Foto.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Kindleerplanonderdeel.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Klas.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Leerkracht.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Leerling.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Leerplan.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/LeerplanOefenreeks.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Leerplanonderdeel.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Niveau.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Oefenreeks.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Overgangsregel.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Rapport.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/RapportLeerplanonderdeel.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Schooljaar.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>be/howest/kidscalcula/model/Subonderdeel.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative 
        to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I just inject my `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` into my DAO, and use `@Transactional` annotations on my methods or on my class.

```
@Repository
public class LeerlingDAOimpl implements LeerlingDAO {
    @Autowired
    public LeerlingDAOimpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
```

**Does anyone have an idea what I forgot, misconfigured? The basic idea is that with this configuration normally, a session is opened whenever a transactional method is being called in my service layer. This would also allow me to load lazy collections in that same transactional method. But for some reason it doesn't even find the thread.**

Comment: Get the stacktrace for the exception. Does the TransactionInterceptor appear in it?

Comment: I found the problem. My annotation scan happened in another xml then my <tx:annotation-driven>. It never found out it had to start a transaction, so there was never a session found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your configuration looks fine, there are several possible reasons:

- You call `@Transactional` method on the object created with `new` (i.e. not obtained from Spring)
- You call `@Transactional` method from another method of the same object (in this case transactional aspect is not applied since it's proxy-based)
- Your object with `@Transactional` methods is declared in the context where `<tx:annotation-driven>` is not in effect (for example, your `@Transactional` object is declared in `...-servlet.xml`, whereas `<tx:annotation-driven>` is only declared in `applicationContext.xml`)

Comment: it is called from a Spring MVC controller, where the service is injected. None of the two first possibilities apply. As for the third:that might be it! I'll test it out. however,I did not split configurations as spring recommends; just one root-context.xml that imports 3 other xml's, my servlet dispatcher, hibernateconfiguration and another one for JSON.

Comment: thank you very much. I've been breaking my head on this issue for about 2 days. Never thought something so trivial would be it! But i'm glad, I learnt another thing about spring that i'll never forget ;)